# Setting Jquery diloag button text does not work as expected

Tags: jquery, button, dialog

I am trying to use jquery dialog, but the following code shows 0, 1 on the button text instead of the text that is specified. I need to use this syntax compared to the other one mentioned in jQuery docs. Can any one help me with the flowing code.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ buttons: [
    {
        text: "Ok",
        click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    }
] });
```

Comment: Your code is **exactly** the same code as the example on http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog so probably there's something wrong with something else...

Comment: Yes this is the code from docs, I did the same for my code. I posted the docs one because, it will be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in a fiddle exactly as you have it:

http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/bGuLj/

Maybe something else is conflicting??

You have options in your code that do not exist for the jquery dialog:
autoShow and beforeClose

You probably want to use autoOpen: false

See updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/bGuLj/5/

Comment: yes, it works in fiddle, i do the same in my code, but it's still the same.

Comment: i cannot post the link, but i will update the original code with the one i am using.

Comment: before close is an event refer here http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-beforeClose. I think it may be because i am using jquery ui 1.8.4 and fiddle is using the latest 1.8.14, do you agree that may be because i have a older version of jquery ui

Comment: Right, thanks. But I still do not see an autoShow option. The fiddle is working so I still can not reproduce your error.

Comment: i got the autoshow option from the old version of dialog. I am still using it. Do you mean that my old version is the problem and updating it to new jQuery-ui-1.8.14 will solve it.

Comment: I could not be sure without testing it. It is certainly something you could try.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$(DialogDiv).dialog({ 
  bgiframe: true, 
  resizable: false, 
  buttons: { 
    { "Save": function() { saveCallback();} }, 
    { "Cancel": function() { cancelCallback(); } 
  }
});
```

JQueryUI expects an `object` for `buttons` but, you are passing `array`.

Comment: As per the jquery docs, you should also be able to pass an array of objects. please refer http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-buttons